# ¿Como se puede implementar un enlace <a> con la librería PHP mailer?

Tags: phpmailer

He intentado agregando la etiqueta correspondiente en el cuerpo del mensaje, pero al momento de revisar el correo enviado, esta no se ve reflejada.

```
$url = 'http://www.dominio.cl';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "mail.dominio.cl";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "news@dominio.cl";
$mail->Password = "123456";

$destinatario2 = "mbeneventi@dominio.cl";
$mail->AddAddress($destinatario2);

$mail->From = "newsletter@dominio.com";
$mail->FromName = "Proveedor";
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Subject = utf8_encode("=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode("Notificacion") . "?=");

$mail->MsgHTML("
    <html>
    <body>
    <a href='".$url."' target='_blank'>Acceda aquí.</a>
    </body>
    </html>
    ");

$mail->IsHTML(true);
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<b>Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo . '</b>';
} else {
    echo "<b>Correo enviado</b>";
}
```

Comment: Podrás mostrar lo que hiciste hasta ahora? De lo contrario va a ser difícil ayudarte o vas a recibir puntos negativos.

Comment: Hola Marcelo, sería ideal que añadieras el código que has intentado y los problemas/dificultades que te estés encontrando. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Mis disculpas, codigo agregado.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHPMailer tienes? Para agregar el cuerpo con el contenido HTML **[la documentación indica](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#using-html-email) que uses `Body`**,  no se habla de `MsgHTML`. Hazlo en el orden que ellos indican: 1º esto: `$mail->IsHTML(true);` y 2º esto, usando `Body`: `$mail->Body("
    <html>
    <body>
    <a href='".$url."' target='_blank'>Acceda aquí.</a>
    </body>
    </html>
    ");` y luego el resto del código.

Answer (score 1):

En la [documentación de PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#using-html-email), se indica que si quieres enviar emails en formato HTML debes indicarlo pasando el valor `true` al método `isHTML`. Algo como esto:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

En esa misma página puedes ver un ejemplo:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('myfriend@example.net', 'My Friend');
$mail->Subject = 'An HTML Message';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = 'Hello, <b>my friend</b>! This message uses HTML!';
```